# Idiomatic sequence slice in Clojure

Tags: clojure, sequence, slice

In Python, there is a convenient way of taking parts of a list called "slicing":

```python
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] # ≡ a = range(1,10)
a[:3] # get first 3 elements
a[3:] # get all elements except the first 3
a[:-3] # get all elements except the last 3
a[-3:] # get last 3 elements
a[3:7] # get 4 elements starting from 3rd (≡ from 3rd to 7th exclusive)
a[3:-3] # get all elements except the first 3 and the last 3
```

Playing with `clojure.repl/doc` in Clojure, I found equivalents for all of them but I'm not sure they are idiomatic.

```clj
(def a (take 10 (iterate inc 1)))
(take 3 a)
(drop 3 a)
(take (- (count a) 3) a)
(drop (- (count a) 3) a)
(drop 3 (take 7 a))
(drop 3 (take (- (count a) 3) a))
```

My question is: how to slice sequences in Clojure? In other words, what is the correct way to return different parts of a sequence?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can simplify all the ones using `count` by using `take-last` or `drop-last` instead:

```clj
(def a (take 10 (iterate inc 1)))
(take 3 a) ; get first 3 elements
(drop 3 a) ; get all elements except the first 3
(drop-last 3 a) ; get all elements except the last 3
(take-last 3 a) ; get last 3 elements
(drop 3 (take 7 a)) ; get 4 elements starting from 3
(drop 3 (drop-last 3 a)) ; get all elements except the first and the last 3
```

And as suggested in the comments below, you can use the [`->>`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) macro to "thread" several operation together. For example, the last two lines could also be written like this:

```clj
(->> a (take 7) (drop 3)) ; get 4 elements starting from 3
(->> a (drop-last 3) (drop 3)) ; get all elements except the first and the last 3
```

I think the two methods are both very readable if you are only applying two operations to a list, but when you have a long string like `take`, `map`, `filter`, `drop`, `first` then using the `->>` macro can make the code much easier to read and probably even easier for to write.

Comment: I would also suggest to use `->>` macro for readability purpose. `(->> a (drop-last 3) (take 4))`

Comment: @Alex Baranosky - Like I said, I don't think it helps much in the case where you're only applying two functions. If  you're applying something more like 5 functions though I think using a threading macro makes the flow of control a lot more clear since you don't have to read inside-to-outside. These are just opinions though, not facts.

Comment: `(range 1 (inc 10))` and `(take 10 (next (range)))` are better alternatives to `(take 10 (iterate inc 1)))`, being closer to the python version in spirit or somewhat more legible IMHO.

Answer (score 26):

Python's notion of a sequence is very different from Clojure's.

In Python,

- a [*sequence*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) is a *finite ordered set indexed by
  non-negative numbers*; and
- a *list* is a mutable sequence which you can add slices to or remove
  slices from.

In Clojure,

- a [*sequence*](http://clojure.org/sequences#Sequences-The%20Seq%20interface) is an interface supporting `first`, `rest`, and
  `cons`;
- a [*list*](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Lists%20%28IPersistentList%29) is an immutable sequential collection with `cons` (or
  `rest`) adding (or removing) `first` elements (returning lists so
  modified, anyway).

The nearest thing in Clojure to a Python list is a [*vector*](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Vectors%20%28IPersistentVector%29). As [Adam Sznajder suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12070100/1562315), you can slice it using [`subvec`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/subvec), though you can't add or remove slices as you can in Python.

`subvec` is a fast constant-time operation, whereas `drop` makes you pay for the number of elements bypassed (`take` makes you pay for the elements you traverse, but these are the ones you are interested in).

Your examples become ...

```clj
(def a (vec (range 1 (inc 10))))

(subvec a 0 3)
; [1 2 3]

(subvec a 3)
; [4 5 6 7 8 9 10]

(subvec a 0 (- (count a) 3))
; [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]

(subvec a (- (count a) 3))
; [8 9 10]

(subvec a 3 (+ 3 4))
; [4 5 6 7]

(subvec a 3 (- (count a) 3))
; [4 5 6 7]
```

Answer (score 12):

There is a function `subvec`. Unfortunately, it only works with vectors so you would have to transform your sequence:

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/subvec

Answer (score 5):

Slicing a sequence is a bit of a "code smell" - a sequence in general is designed for sequential access of items.

If you are going to do a lot of slicing / concatenation, there are much better data structures available, in particular checkout the RRB-Tree vector implementation:

- https://github.com/clojure/core.rrb-vector

This supports very efficient `subvec` and `catvec` operations.